# Selenium webdriver - End of the page(using vertical scroll)

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How can I check if I reached the end of the page (using vertical scroll)?

From the Webdriver - press the page down key till end of the page. Using for loop I have done this :

```
for(int di=0; di<40; di++) { 
   driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).sendKeys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN);
   Thread.sleep(1500);
}
```

My for loop always executed 40 times even its less size. So I need help how I can check if it reached the end of the page, because if I reached then I will break and come out of the loop.

Comment: Does the page in question contain a table that you are scrolling, or is it just a potentially very long page of other kinds of elements?  If it's a table, then you get the total number of rows and scroll until the last row is shown.  Otherwise, as suggested in NarendraR's answer, you need to know of a specific element that will be at the bottom of the page and scroll until it is visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the support, Finally got a idea and implemented its met my expectations

First measure the scroll height

```
 JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
            long value = (Long) executor.executeScript("return document.body.scrollHeight");
```

and looping

```
for (int f = 500; f <= value; f += 500) {
            JavascriptExecutor jsc = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
            jsc.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0," + f + ")");
            Thread.sleep(1500);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think First you have to pick an element which exist at the end of page.
Lets say there is one footer label with id `company-email`

```
boolean flag = true;
while(flag){
if(driver.findElements(By.id("company-email").size()>0){

    flag = false;
}
else{

   driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).sendKeys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN);
   Thread.sleep(1500);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to scroll till end of a page :

```
public static void scrollToEndOfPage(WebDriver driver) {
        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)");
    }
```

and after it has been executed you can perform further operations.

If you want to scroll to a particular WebElement you can use below method :

```
 public static void scrollToElement(WebDriver driver, WebElement element) {
            ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element);
        }
```

Hope that helps you.